# Find the time interval between oscillations of SHM.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, classical-mechanics

[image]

Parts i) and ii) I can solve.

But for part iii) I can't do, as I don't know which equation describes the SHM motion? Is it $y=0.5\sin(1.2t)$ or $y=0.5\cos(1.2t)$ or $x=0.5\sin(1.2t)+2.5$?

I thought the correct approach was to differentiate $x=0.5\sin(1.2t)+2.5$ with respect to time $t$ and equate to $0.48$ and solve to get the $2$ different times. But it isn't working.

Could someone please help me solve part iii)?

Here is the official answer:

[image]

What I would like to know is how this "$\left[t_0 = \cfrac{\sin^{-1}(0.6)}{1.2};\space t_1 = \cfrac{\cos^{-1}(0.6)}{1.2}\right]$" was deduced?

With best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your third equation for SHM should completely describe the system up to some (indeterminable) phase shift. Your method of differentiating the equation should work fine for part iii. Did you consider that "speed" is not the same as "velocity"? ie, set |X'|=0.48, and not X'=0.48. Also, since P is moving "towards" O at $t_1, t_2$, it makes sense to use the cosine function: $$\Big|\frac{d(0.5 cos(1.2 t)+2.5)}{dt}\Big|=0.48$$

$$t = \frac{5}{6} \Big(2 \pi n \pm sin^{-1}\frac{4}{5}\Big),\ \ \ \ n\in\mathbb{Z} $$
$$t = \frac{5}{6} \Big(2 \pi n +\pi \pm sin^{-1}\frac{4}{5}\Big),\ \ \ \ n\in\mathbb{Z} $$
$$t_1=0.7727,\ t_2=1.8452,\ t_3=3.3907$$ $$\Delta t_{12}=1.0725,\ \Delta t_{23}=1.5455$$

Comment: Excellent answer. If you look at my edited post you will see that you have got the correct answer, so well done. I'm about to award you the bounty, i just need to know two more things, firstly, my maths teacher is certain that $x=0.5sin(1.2t)+2.5$ is correct so why when i differentiate it, it doesn't give correct answers? In other words i don't understand what you mean by "Also, since P is moving "towards" O at t1,t2, it makes sense to use the cosine function". The second thing is where did this "[t0 = (sin-10.6)/1.2; t1 = (cos-10.6)/1.2]" come from? Thank you.

Comment: Graph the sine function. It first moves away from $\mathcal{O}$ and then turns around and starts heading back. The sine function does give the correct answer, but you have to be careful with the "direction". If you gather the times from the sine function, you have to throw out the first positive t value and use only the next three times. (I used the cosine to avoid this).

Comment: I am seeking to reconcile the indicated inverses. In both cases, it seems that 0.8 (and not 0.6) should be inside the inverse function. But they produce the correct answer, so they must be equivalent through some identity or shift.

Answer (score 2):

All three of your equations describe the same SHM.

In part (iii), we are interested only in velocity and time, so use 
$\frac{dx}{dt}=(0.5)(1.2) \cos(1.2t) $
Consider the cos graph from $0$ to $2\pi$, which is $0$ to 5.4 in our problem (sorry I dont know how to draw it here). Consider
$\vert \frac{dx}{dt} \vert = 0.48 $. On the graph, where the gradient is negative, this occurs where $ \frac{dx}{dt} = 0.48 $ and $ \frac{dx}{dt} = -0.48 $. Solving these equations gives $t_1 = 0.54$, and $ t_2 = 2.08$. And from the symmetry of the graph, the next two values (where the gradient is positive) are $t_3 = 5.24 - 2.08$ and $t_4 = 5.24 - 0.54$.

Comment: Hi there thanks for your answer "All three of your equations describe the same SHM": Are you sure about that?

Comment: All 3 equations are solutions of the equation $d^2x/dt^2+(1.2)^2 x = 0$, and that's why I say that they all describe the same SHM. In my experience of teaching this topic, it is always helpful to draw a graph (in this case velocity/time), as an aid in identifying all the solutions.